# Multithreaded idiomatic find first of substrings in a string using modern C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, stl, find, idioms

It is easy to find a string in a set of strings using `set::find` or first of a set of strings in a set of strings using `std::find_first_of`. But I think that STL doesn't handle this case of find_first_of set of strings (substrings) in a string. For low latency reasons I use parallel execution, would you please let me know if this implementation is idiomatic using modern C++ :

```
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <atomic>
#include <execution>
#include <iostream>

class Intent{
    const std::list<std::string> m_Context;
    const std::string m_Name;
    std::atomic_bool m_Found;
public:
    Intent(const std::list<std::string> context, const std::string name)
        : m_Context(context)
        , m_Name(name)
        , m_Found(false)
        {}
    Intent(const Intent & intent) = delete;
    Intent & operator=(const Intent & intent) = delete;
    Intent(Intent && intent) : m_Context(std::move(intent.m_Context))
                    , m_Name(std::move(intent.m_Name))
                    , m_Found(static_cast< bool >(intent.m_Found))
                    {}

    bool find(const std::string & sentence)
    {
        for_each( std::execution::par
                , std::begin(m_Context)
                , std::end(m_Context)
                , [& m_Found = m_Found, & sentence](const std::string & context_element){
                    //
                    // Maybe after launching thread per context_element one of them make intent Found
                    // so no need to run string::find in the remaining threads.
                    //
                    if(!m_Found){ 
                        if(sentence.find(context_element) != std::string::npos)
                        {
                            m_Found = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            );
        return m_Found;
    }
    const bool getFound() const {return m_Found;}
    const std::string & getName() const {return m_Name;}
};

int main()
{
    Intent intent({"hello", "Hi", "Good morning"}, "GREETING");
    std::cout << intent.find("Hi my friend.");
}
```

Comment: I doubt parallel execution would help much with `std::list`, seeing as you have to scan it sequentially just to get to any middle node. At least use `std::vector` to have any hope of improvement. And of course, you need to test with way more than three elements - just spinning up a thread would take much longer than walking over three strings.

Comment: I don't need reading Nth index, so I can't see the advantage of vector. And for data-parallel concurrency, what is the difference between iterating std::list or iterating std::vector?

Comment: I can imagine an implementation that breaks the vector into chunks and runs multiple threads each working on one chunk. It's `O(1)` to get an iterator to `k`th chunk. I'm hard-pressed to imagine an implementation doing the same with `std::list`.

Comment: if you're working with list use parallelized `std::search()` instead of `.find()` and remove `execution_par` from `for_each`. check performance anyway.

Comment: and you can choose algo.

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин I'm not sure I understand how `std::search` would be preferable to `std::find_if` (or `std::any_of`) and the link didn't help.  Why not provide an answer to the question to make it clear?

Comment: @TedLyngmo depends on this app goals. supports reverse search where yours doesn't

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин OP wants to check if any string in a list of strings (`{"hello", "Hi", "Good morning"}`)  is a substring in the provided string (`"Hi my friend."`) an OP wonders if the approach taken is the idiomatic one. That's what the question is about. Searching in reverse would certainly be possible even with `std::find_if` and `std::any_of` but ... why? I don't see any benefit of using `std::search` here.

Comment: @TedLyngmo `std::find()` and its stuff doesn't work with reverse iterators.

Comment: @TedLyngmo https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find    `template< class ExecutionPolicy, class ForwardIt, class UnaryPredicate >
ForwardIt find_if( ExecutionPolicy&& policy, ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last,
                   UnaryPredicate p );`     And do not bother me anymore

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин Yes, that's the same link I put in my answer to help OP to find more information about `std::find_if`. What's your point? Did you somehow come to the conclusion that `ForwardIt` means that it can not be used with reverse iterators? Did you consider the fact that a reverse iterator can be (and usually is) a forward iterator, just going in reverse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the idiomatic way of doing it would be to use [`std::find_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find). Then you don't need the `atomic<bool>` either.

```
// return iterator to found element or end()
auto find(const std::string & sentence)
{
    return std::find_if( std::execution::par
            , std::begin(m_Context)
            , std::end(m_Context)
            , [&sentence](const std::string & context_element) {
                return sentence.find(context_element) != std::string::npos;
            }
        );
}
```

If you really only want a `bool` you could use [`std::any_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of):

```
bool find(const std::string & sentence)
{
    return std::any_of( std::execution::par
            , std::begin(m_Context)
            , std::end(m_Context)
            , [&sentence](const std::string & context_element) {
                return sentence.find(context_element) != std::string::npos;
            }
        );
}
```

You may want to consider using a `std::vector` instead of a `std::list` too.  `vector`s provide random access iterators while `list`s only provide bidirectional iterators.